# Open gmail client using jquery

Tags: email, client

Using mail to tag i able to open outlook which is default email client on my machine.

What I really need click mailto gmail will open instead of outlook. Using jquery or javascript code only. Only client side

Answer (score 0):

You can only open the defualt mail client with 
`mailto`

In your case Outlook.

Comment: ok,is there anyother way to open gmail,and outlook email clients

Comment: No. It is up to the user to choose what their default mail client is.